# HI i need a help my simple programing is with NameError

Tags: python, class, nameerror

HI i need a help my simple programing is with NameError, my code :

```
class Televisao():
    def __init__(self,boolean, channel):
        self.channel = 2
        self.boolean = False
    def main():
       tvhome =Televisao()
    print tvhome.channel

    if __name__== "__main__" :
        main()
```

> NameError: name 'tvhome' is not defined

Comment: Please review your code formatting and provide the full error traceback. But note that `"Televisao" != "televisao"`.

Comment: Looks like you meant `tvhome = Televisao()` and not `televisao()` with no capital `t`. Therefore this appears to be off-topic as it is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Televisao:
    def __init__(self, is_on, channel):
        self.is_on = is_on
        self.channel = channel

def main():
   tvhome = Televisao(True, 13)
   print(tvhome.channel)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Televisao():
    def __init__(self,boolean, channel):
         self.channel = 2
         self.boolean = False

if __name__== "__main__" :
    tvhome = Televisao()
    print tvhome.channel
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems that you have create instance inside function and call it from outside.

```
 def main():
     tvhome = Televisao() # now tvhome is local variable.

 print tvhome.channel  # you will get the error : undefined
```

**Update:**
Another errror will occur, as you call

```
tvhome = Televisao() # without its __init__ parameters boolean , channel
```